# Change particular text or url in page content on wordpress using MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

1)I have 85 pages in my website, in that i like to change particular url which have used in all pages.

2)I need update query for select particular posts and change repeated things in that content

need to replace below url `anbomanufacturing.com/LitForm.html`;

with this url`192.185.104.157/~anbomanu/product-literature`

Comment: Could you add the specific parts you want to replace and what do you want it replaced with?

Comment: @FilipeSilva need to replace below url 'http://www.anbomanufacturing.com/LitForm.html' with this url'http://192.185.104.157/~anbomanu/product-literature'. it have used  in all the pages. for this replace i has spend minimum 3 minutes per page(for your information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE yourTableName
SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName , 'www.anbomanufacturing.com/LitForm.html', 
                 'http://192.185.104.157/~anbomanu/product-literature');
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this, and place this code in your functions.php file to replace the link from the content:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'link_replacer');

function link_replacer ($content = '') {
    $pattern = "/anbomanufacturing.com/LitForm.html/";
    $replace = "192.185.104.157/~anbomanu/product-literature";

    return preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $content );
}
```

for more information take a look on the [the_content Filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)

Comment: i got above error 'Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in E:\wamp1\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\anbo\functions.php on line 161' while use the above functions